# Force EF to save specified decimal places

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, decimal, decimal-point

I defined some `decimal` properties in my entities:

```
public class Entity1
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public decimal Value {get; set;}
}
```

and because I want to save **maximum** 4 decimal places for my decimals, in my configuration files I defined:

```
this.Property(t => t.Value).HasPrecision(18, 4);
```

so the result is `Value` field with 4 decimal places in my `Entity1` table.

How can I force `EF` to save only decimal places that used in `Value`'s value?

for example:

- if Value = 0.05 then it save 0.05 and when I read the Value from Db it shows me 0.05 and not 0.0500
- if Value = 0.050 then it save 0.050
- if Value = 0.05000 then it save 0.0500 (because maximum decimal places is 4)

In the other word, I want to `EF` save decimal places that end user specified in `Value`.

Comment: Can İ ask why you want to save 0.05 as 0.0500?

Comment: @AdilMammadov: I don't want to save 0.05 as 0.0500, My question is that how to save 0.05 as 0.05 and not as 0.0500 but EF save it as 0.0500

Comment: How do you know it is saved as 0.0500? You can't possibly know just because you see it as 0.0500 with an SQL query, it's really saved like this. Have you observed the created query?

Comment: Is your concern about displaying the retrieved numbers the way they were entered, or actually saving the exact precision that was entered, for mathematical purposes?

Comment: if it's with saving the exact precision, you might want to look at using a `single` data type rather than a `decimal` in your EF model. A `single` is a floating-point value.

Comment: @AnnL.: My concern is about displaying the numbers the way entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your concern is about display the numbers the way they were entered and not as much with preserving the exact precision for mathematical reasons, you have a couple of options.

I am assuming that you actually need the value to be numeric within the database, for querying or calculation purposes.  Otherwise, you could save it as a string.

You could save a second value, representing the precision of the entered value, and use that to create a format string for your value:

```
public decimal  Value { get; set; }
public byte     ValuePrecision { get; set; }

public string FormatValue()
{
    string fmtString = string.Format("{{0:N{0}}}", this.ValuePrecision);
    return string.Format(fmtString, this.Value);
}
```

DISCLAIMER:  code was done from memory and has not been tested.